# gSOAP does **not** close sockets?

Tags: c++, sockets, soap, gsoap

I've an issue with gSoap - it's not closing the socket.. Here's the situation: the application is working fine, but when I call "reload" function, it cannot reconnect.. Here's a piece of code:

```
soap_destroy( &m_soapObj );
soap_end( &m_soapObj );
soap_done(&m_soapObj);

sleep(1);

soap_init(&m_soapObj);

//m_ptrThis should be initialized already
assert( m_ptrThis != NULL );
m_soapObj.user = &m_ptrThis;

m_soapObj.accept_timeout = nAcceptTimeout;
m_ptrThreadPool->SetNumThreads( nNumThreads );  
m_nSocketListener = soap_bind(&m_soapObj, NULL, nPort, nBacklog);
if (!soap_valid_socket(m_nSocketListener))
{
    throw Exception(
    "Cannot start listening on port: %d", nPort );          
}
```

and it throws.. When I try to use soap_free, the program crashes, as I don't create new Soap object, just initialize it again. SO, soap_done should work. And the interesting thing is, that this does **not** happen every time.

It's very strange.. and urgent :/

Thanks a lot in advance

**EDIT** The problem is solved. Many thanks to Duck!

Comment: What's the error it is throwing on?  It looks as if you can look use soap.errnum and soap_print_fault() to find out.  Are you closing the socket beforehand?  Are you not using SO_REUSEADDR and restarting too soon?

Comment: Hi, I wrote here earlier but something have happened, probably because the site was down.. anyway.. Thank you very much! That worked! I added SO_REUSEADDR and everything is fine.. It's a dummy mistake, but I'm not familiarized with this gSoap library at all..just had to fix a bug in a application, written from someone else..It's really hard to fix such problem immediately, when you don't have any time to read anything for such 3rd-party library.. Thank u so much for your help!

Comment: I tried soap_print_fault and it 'said' just that the socket cannot be reopened. The developer, who had written this application, has put a 'wait(1);' after soap_done, but it wasn't enough at all. And the application is processing about 500-800 requests per second, so I could't set a longer wait. So, I mean, that the problem really was in the time, because if I wait about, let's say, 30sec, the socket was reopened successfully. Whatever, thanks again for your help!

Comment: @Duck - if you like, you could move your comment as answer, to be able to accept it and to "give" you some reputation. This really helped me and solved my issue, thanks again (:

Comment: Kiril Kirov - Sure, I am glad it helped and things worked out.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find out exactly what error is being thrown.

It is possible you are getting an "Address Already in Use" error from bind().  You can try to correct for this by using setsockopt() - or the equivalent soap call - with the SO_REUSEADDR option.

[This](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html) link provides a concise explanation.